# Unable to find crate that is listed in [build-dependencies] section

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I try to compile my project with the command `cargo build`.

**build.rs**

```
extern crate csv;

use std::path::Path;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::BufWriter;
use std::io::Write;

#[allow(non_snake_case)]
fn processCSV(filename: &str, sourcePath: &str, enumName: &str) {
    println!("Generate rust source code from schema {}",filename);

    let mut ret: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    let mut rdr = csv::Reader::from_file(filename).unwrap().flexible(true);
    for record in rdr.records().map(|r| r.unwrap()) {
    }
    let path = Path::new(sourcePath);
    let file = match OpenOptions::new().write(true).create(true).open(&path) {
        Ok(file) => file,
        Err(..) => panic!("Cannot create file {}",path.display()),
    };
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(file);

    writer.write_all(b"test\n");
}

fn main() {
    processCSV("../schemas/Test.csv", "./src/mod/common/StatusCode.rs", "StatusCode");
}
```

and **Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "rust-test"
version = "0.0.1"
build = "build.rs"

[lib]
path = "src/lib.rs"

[dependencies]

[build-dependencies]
csv = "*"
```

I can see this error :

> src/lib.rs:1:1: 1:18 error: can't find crate for `csv`
>
> src/lib.rs:1 extern crate csv;

but when I change `flexible(true)` to `flexible(false)` it compiles just fine without any errors. What do I need to do to fix this?

I am using Rust 1.2.0 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: which rust version are you using? it seems to be your problem: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18699

Comment: I have tried 1.2.0 and also 1.3.0-beta.3 (2a89bb6ba 2015-08-11)

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk: How is the `flexible` function of the `csv::Reader` related to flexible target specification?

Comment: The error is reported for `src/lib.rs` but we only see the source for `build.rs`.  I believe the answer from @Shepmaster is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the thread! Helped me a bit with a small issue.

Check out the walkdir crate btw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing `flexible(false)` for `flexible(true)` makes no difference for me; both fail. The problem is that you've chosen `build-dependencies` for some reason, instead of just `dependencies`.

Using the **src/lib.rs** file that you provided in your answer, and this **Cargo.toml** file:

```
[package]
name = "stack-overflow"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["A. Developer <a.developer@example.com>"]

[dependencies]
csv = "*"
```

It compiles fine.

If you need to access a dependency both in your **build.rs** and in your project, you need to include the dependency in *both* sections.

Comment: I didn't describe my problem correctly, I forgot to mention that I had problem with the file build.rs. So I assume "build-dependecies" should be used for this case. I also tried to copy "csv" to "dependecies" and yes it works. But I think it is not correct and in cargo (or rust compiler) there is some error how dependencies are resolved.

Comment: @now2 *problem with the file build.rs* — but your error message says `src/lib.rs [...] can't find crate for csv`. That's why I assumed that the code you were showing was the contents of `src/lib.rs`. Your question still doesn't actually show `src/lib.rs`, but see the last sentence of my edited answer for a guess.

Answer (score 4):

A build dependency is a dependency for [a build script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html), which is a helper binary compiled and run before your main crate is built (designed to be used for code-generation, and building/finding native C libraries, etc.).

Normal dependencies used by the main code should just fall into the "dependencies" section, e.g.

```
[dependencies]
csv = "0.14"
```

There's also a "dev-dependencies" section, which are dependencies that are only needed for testing, i.e. they are compiled and used only for `cargo test`. This allows crates to depend on, for example, [`quickcheck`](https://crates.io/crates/quickcheck) for running tests without contaminating the main artifact.

In summary, running `cargo build` will do something like:

1. build any `build-dependencies`
2. build the build script (pointing the compiler to the built build-dependencies), and run it
3. build any `dependencies`
4. build the main crate (pointing the compiler to the built dependencies)

Running `cargo test` adds:

5. build any `dev-dependencies`
6. build the main crate with `--test` to create a test runner for any in-source `#[test]`s (pointing the compiler to both the dependencies and dev-dependencies)
7. build any external examples or tests, also pointing to both the dependencies and dev-dependencies

Comment: I have edited my question see my comment to Shepmaster's answer.