# How to use external crates in a Cargo build script?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have this file structure

```
Test
│   .gitignore
│   build.rs
│   Cargo.toml
│
├───.vscode
│       tasks.json
│
├───src
│       main.rs
```

I have this Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "test"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["xtricman"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
regex = "*"
```

I have this build.rs

```
fn main() {
    let mt = regex::Regex::new(r"_[1-9][0-9]+.rs|_0.rs\z").unwrap().find("gdf_980.rs");
    let mts = if mt.is_some() {
        println!("{}", mt.unwrap().as_str());
    } else {
        println!("None");
    };
}
```

I want to use the regex crate in my build script, but I get a compile error

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type or module `regex`
 --> build.rs:2:14
  |
2 |     let mt = regex::Regex::new(r"_[1-9][0-9]+.rs|_0.rs\z").unwrap().find("gdf_980.rs");
  |              ^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `regex`
```

Does Cargo only support std in `build.rs`?

Comment: If you're using Rust 2015, then you'll also need to add it to your crate root: `extern crate regex;`

Comment: They are not using Rust 2015: `edition = "2018"`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add the crate to your `[build-dependencies]` key:

```
[build-dependencies]
regex = "*"
```

You can **also** add the crate to the `[dependencies]` key if your crate needs it.

See also:

- [Build dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#build-dependencies) in the Cargo documentation
- [How do I use external crates in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21655032/155423)
- [Unable to find crate that is listed in [build-dependencies] section](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32522870/155423)